# ViewSwitcher not showing initial view when programmatically updating views and switching

Tags: android

Below is a test project for a concept that I'm experimenting with. The purpose is to dynamically create two views and slide from one to another.

However, the ViewSwitcher *never* shows the initial view !

**The Activity**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ViewSwitcher mViewSwitcher;
    private Button mButton;
    private Animation mAnimSlideInRight;
    private Animation mAnimSlideOutLeft;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mViewSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcher1);
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        mAnimSlideInRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_right);
        mAnimSlideOutLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_left);

        // Fish image
        final ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
        imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.fish_one);
        imageView1.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        // Fire image
        final ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
        imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.fire);
        imageView2.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mViewSwitcher.removeAllViews();

                mViewSwitcher.addView(imageView1, 0);
                mViewSwitcher.addView(imageView2, 1);

                mViewSwitcher.setInAnimation(mAnimSlideInRight);
                mViewSwitcher.setOutAnimation(mAnimSlideOutLeft);

                mViewSwitcher.showNext();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**The Layout XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Flip" />

    <ViewSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/viewSwitcher1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </ViewSwitcher>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**animation: slide_in_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

**animation: slide_out_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

for the images, I just used a google'd fish image and a fire image.

**Problem:** the fish image is never, ever visible :-(
Instead, the view is white and the fire image image slides in. (Fish never slides out)

What can I do to make the fish slide out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out - the solution is to give the view time ! Don't rush it, LOL!
Below is the code for the updated `mButton.setOnClickListener()`

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{

    // Button callback
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        mViewSwitcher.post(new Runnable()
        {
            // Runnable that removes all views and places the images in the view
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                mViewSwitcher.removeAllViews();

                mViewSwitcher.addView(imageView1, 0);
                mViewSwitcher.addView(imageView2, 1);

                // Nested Runnable that triggers the sliding animation
                mViewSwitcher.post(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        mViewSwitcher.setInAnimation(mAnimSlideInRight);
                        mViewSwitcher.setOutAnimation(mAnimSlideOutLeft);
                        mViewSwitcher.showNext();
                    }
                });// end of nested Runnable

            }
        });// end of Runnable

    }
});// end of OnClickListener
```